# How to insert sms into sent folder on android

Tags: android, sms

After sending a sms, write the sms into sent folder. 
How can i do it on android?

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(to, null, text, null, null);
```

Comment: I've never used this, but doesn't that happen automatically? Anything else sounds awfully weird to me at least...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "sent folder" in Android.

Some SMS clients may have a "sent folder". You would have to contact the developers of those applications to find out if there is a documented and supported API for manipulating that folder. For example, there is no documented and supported API for the Messenger application that is part of the Android open source project.

Comment: the sent folder that i said is content://sms/outbox/.

Comment: @sweetier: That is not part of the operating system. That is an undocumented and unsupported content provider published by the Messenger application. Devices that have replaced this application may or may not offer that content provider. Google has specifically told you to avoid using it: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Really appreciate it.